# Variation of SELECT * - all columns except those explicitly referenced

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there any way to convert one column and be able to reference all the other columns without naming them explicitly?

Normally I would do this:

```
SELECT
      ,[Id]
      ,[Name]
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[CreateDate], 104) as [CreateDate] 
  FROM Customers
```

What I could do in the perfect world would be:

```
SELECT
      *
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[CreateDate], 104) as [CreateDate] 
  FROM Customers
```

Where * would mean all columns that are not explicitly stated in the query.

Is there a keyword that enables one to do this or is there some other way? Please keep in mind that it has to be doable in a query - no changing tables, making views, SPs or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a programmatic way to say "all the columns except this one" unless you wanted to build dynamic SQL from `sys.columns` based on a list you provide the query (it would be *very* difficult to derive the list of referenced columns from the query dynamically, especially as you introduce joins, where clauses, etc).

But there is a pretty trivial way to do this without typing them all. Just expand your table in Object Explorer, and drag the "Columns" node onto the query editor window. Now just remove the CreateDate column from the list.

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do to avoid typing a long list of fields is select the table name in the editor and then press alt-f1. That is the same thing than typing "sp_help table". You will get a result set with all the column names of that table. I copy that list into the editor and add the commas.

An easy way to add commas at the end of all the lines by using the search and replace in the editor:

1. Select only the lines with the column name.
2. Check "Use" and select "Regular Expressions" from the drop down.
3. In the "Find What" type $ (Dollar sign means end of the line)
4. in the "Replace With" type ,

That will add a comma to the end of each selected line.

Another way is to right click on the table in the Object Explorer and click on "select top 1000" option that will create a script for you in another text editor window.

Comment: These both seem a lot more tedious than just dragging the "Columns" node onto the editor. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand, you are right, I did not know that you can drag the columns node :) I learn something new everyday!